# Need help using an implementation of XTEA in Java

Tags: java, xtea

I need to encrypt some `String` using XTEA algorithm, and found [this code](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/security/XTEA.java) but I'm not sure how to use it and I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Here's how I'm using it:

```
XTEA mXTEA = new XTEA();        
mXTEA.setKey(XTEA_KEY.getBytes());
byte[] b = someString.getBytes();
mXTEA.encrypt(b, 0, b.length);
```

More specifically, I'm not sure what are the last two parameters of `encrypt`. I assumed that `off` is some offset and `len` is the length of the input stream.

**Edit**

Her's the full stack trace:

```
08-12 16:42:03.475: E/AndroidRuntime(23894): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=14; index=14
08-12 16:42:03.475: E/AndroidRuntime(23894):    at   xxx.XTEA.encryptBlock(XTEA.java:56)
08-12 16:42:03.475: E/AndroidRuntime(23894):    at xxx.XTEA.encrypt(XTEA.java:43)
```

Anybody can help?

**Answer**

As suggested by John Skeet, I the string must be padded to get to a multiple of 8:

```
int len = myString.length();
int newLen = len + (8- len % 8);

while(myString.length()<newSize){
    myString += "\0";
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Please show the full stack trace. (Additionally, I'd strongly discourage you from using the overload of `String.getBytes` which doesn't specify an encoding.)

Comment: I added the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code and the [Wikipedia entry on XTEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) it looks like the problem is that it only works on blocks of 8 bytes, and you're providing 14 bytes (which isn't a multiple of 8).

You'll probably need to add some padding, and either just chop off trailing 0s from the plaintext, or if you need to be able to represent U+0000 in the actual text, you could add a bit of data to say how much *real* data there is.

Comment: You're right, so I padded my string with null character. Thanks.